# How to make create an enum similar to an existing one gets compilation error on first one definition changes?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a C# application which is using an external library. This library defines an enum. I have created a similar enum in my code (one to one matching ) so that my application code is generic and not coupled with external library. How can I do this such that, I will get a compilation error whenever the original enum changes. This way, whenever the library is updated, it will throw an error so that I can update my internal enum as well.

```
// Lib definition
public enum Lib_Enum_Type
{
    Auto = 0,
    Type0 = 1,
    Type2 = 2
}

// App Definition
public enum App_Enum_Type
{
    AutoData = 0,
    Type0Data = 1,
    Type2Data = 2
}
```

What I am expecting is, on updating the library, if an element is added or value changed to Lib_Enum_Type, I should get a compilation error so that I can update App_Enum_Type accordingly.

Comment: You can't get a compiler error without writing some form of analyzer, but you can easliy fix this with reflection and use a unit-test to ensure this is handled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no inbuilt way to do this. However, you could add a method to your test project that verifies the enums via reflection (`Enum.GetValues(typeof(Lib_Enum_Type))`) and compares it to what you expect to exist.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use a different data structure that directly maps one value to another, such as a `Dictionary`.